# scrollbar cracks layout of fixed position sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm having a sitewrapper with `width: 100%;` which gets pushed to the right and brings in a `position: fixed;` sidebar if a specific button is clicked. This works pretty good so far, the only problem I have is, if the site loads with a scrollbar, it creates a crack between the fixed position div. Does anyone of you have an advice?

```
#right_sidebar {
  width: 160px; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: #ffb005; 
  position: fixed; 
  right: -160px;
}
```

and on click:

```
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $right_sidebar.animate({right: 0}, transDelay);
    $outer_wrapper.animate({marginLeft: -160}, transDelay);
});
```

**Edit:** FIDDLE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/o56jt2fe/1/), please press on green background.

Comment: can try something if you could provide with some more code(problem in action) :)

Comment: @theScorpion thanks, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/o56jt2fe/1/

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 'a crack' ?

Comment: @theScorpion as you can see there is a white space between both divs if you click on the green one and it slides left.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for u.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o56jt2fe/2/)

adding this did the trick:

```
body, html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the 100% width is the problem - try this:

```
<div id="outer_wrapper">
    <div id="right_sidebar">dfsdf</div>
</div>

#outer_wrapper  {
/*  width: 100%; */ 
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: green; 
}
#right_sidebar {
    position: fixed; 
    right: -160px;
    width: 160px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```